# Examples of well-known unsolved problems, in subjects don't related to number theory, that have several equivalent formulations

Tags: reference-request, big-list, open-problem

I know statements for some unsolved problems related in some way to number theory, being stated (I refer for each one of these unsolved problems) several equivalent formulations, for example: these are the Riemann hypothesis, Goldbach conjecture (see the equivalent statement from [1]), the twin prime problem in terms of particular values of some number theoretic functions (see as reference [2]), if I refer well the determination of even perfect numbers (in terms of particular values of the sum of divisors function, and also Lucas-Lehmer test determining what integers are Mersenne primes)..., or as a last example to get a closed-form for the Apèry's constant computing integrals or series as Dirichlet series (see [3]).

All these problems are related to the category of number theory (or analytic number theory).

> **Question.** I would like to know* remarkable unsolved problems, in different categories of mathematics than number theory/analytic number theory, for which were stated several equivalent formulations. **Many thanks.**

I refer that I know the previous problems thus I am not interested precisely in the mentioned in the introductory paragraph.

*Only it is required **a reference in which was published the equivalent formulation**, and if you want **as is known the unsolved problem or a general reference** for this unsolved problem that you refer in the mathematical bibliography.

I've flagged the post because I feel that the downvote that was casted is harassement.

### References:

[1] The article dedicated to *Goldbach Conjecture* from the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld.

[2] The article dedicated to *Twin Primes* from the encyclopedia Wolfram MathWorld.

[3] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, UTM Springer (1976).

Comment: I hope that the question is clear and interesting, I seach references for remarkable unsolved problems in subjects different than number theory, that have a genuine formulation and at least a different one equivalent formulation. I added the tags (reference-request) and (big-list), if you think that other additional tag can be suitable feel free to enrich the post editing it.

Comment: I assume you're familiar with `P = NP`?

Comment: I didn't know if there is some equivalent form for the problem @barrycarter If it is the case, please expand your comment in an answer. Many thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Let $X$ be any problem that has been proved to be NP-complete (there are hundreds of them). Then $P=NP$ is equivalent to $X$ is in P.

Comment: I didn't know it; I know that it is a Clay problem but I'm not familiarized with this problem. Many thanks @GerryMyerson Feel free to expand your comment in an answer adding the references.

Comment: I get the impression that the Jacobian conjecture is well-known, unsolved, not Number Theory, and has many equivalent formulations, but I don't know enough about it to post an answer.

Comment: Any thanks many thanks for your contributions, that are perfect as usual @GerryMyerson

Comment: Here is a post suggesting Köthe's conjecture should qualify: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781100/equivalent-formulations-of-the-k%C3%B6the-s-conjecture

Comment: I add the reference for the Wikipedia *Köthe conjecture*

Comment: van den Essen, A., Kuroda, S., Crachiola, A.J. (2021). The Jacobian Conjecture: New Equivalences. In: Polynomial Automorphisms and the Jacobian Conjecture. Frontiers in Mathematics. Birkhäuser, Cham. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-60535-3_4 looks interesting.

Comment: If you want add your three examples cited in comments as an answer (P=NP, Köthe's conjecture and Jacobian conjecture) professor @GerryMyerson

Comment: No time now. Maybe later.

Comment: I think it could be helpful to explain a little of your motivation here. If you are looking for an example of “two problems that don’t look like the same problem, but are” to show a non-expert something about the structure of mathematical thinking, you need a question the n-e will see as *interesting*, which P=NP isn’t. In that case I’d relax “unsolved” and go back to Euclid: “parallel lines exist” == “similar triangles exist”. But you may have a different purpose in mind.

Comment: My motivation is ask, to know about these, examples of unsolved problems in mathematicas (don't related to number theory/analytic number theory) for which were stated several equivalent formulations @MartinKochanski I'm curious about it (and I trhink that it should be an interesting and curious question for many persons). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

User @barrycarter suggested $P=NP$. Let's expand on that.

Loosely speaking, $P$ is the set of problems that can be solved in time polynomial in the length of the input; $NP$ is the set of problems for which a proposed solution can be checked in time polynomial in the length of the input. Clearly, $P\subseteq NP$. The question is whether $P=NP$

A problem is said to be *NP-complete* if every problem in $NP$ can be reduced to it in polynomial time. If an NP-complete problem is in $P$, then $P=NP$, and conversely, if $P=NP$, then every NP-complete problem is in $P$.

So we see that for every NP-complete problem $X$, the statement "$X$ is in $P$" is equivalent to $P=NP$.

Now, there are hundreds – maybe thousands, by now – of problems that have been proved to be NP-complete. See. for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems where $130$ NP-complete problems are listed.

Comment: Many thnaks for your great answer.